# Xamarin build error in android wear

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am trying to build an app for an **android wear** device using Xamarin and Mvvmcross.

**But I always get the same build error:**

```
7>  3 errors
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor.java(8,49): javac.exe error :  error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor.java(8,49): javac.exe error :         android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnDismissedListener
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor.java(8,49): javac.exe error : 
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnPreSwipeListenerImplementor.java(8,49): javac.exe error :  error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnPreSwipeListenerImplementor.java(8,49): javac.exe error :      android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnPreSwipeListener
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnPreSwipeListenerImplementor.java(8,49): javac.exe error : 
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnSwipeProgressChangedListenerImplementor.java(8,49): error :  error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnSwipeProgressChangedListenerImplementor.java(8,49): error :        android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnSwipeProgressChangedListener
7>C:\git\AMDM\AMDM\AMDM.Wear\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnSwipeProgressChangedListenerImplementor.java(8,49): error :
```

I cannot find the solution for this build error, does anybody know a solution?

**Info**

- Minimum android version: API lvl 25
- Xamarin.Android.Wear: v2.0.1.1
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Wear: v26.0.2

[Github example](https://github.com/kevingoos/WearTest)

Comment: Can you provide a sample project so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @tequilaslammer I will at that this afternoon

Comment: @tequilaslammer I added a sample on the following link: https://github.com/kevingoos/WearTest